# Connect to internet through network connection inside network namespace without setting as a default route

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, network-namespace

I need to do a setup like this (with Linux):

- I want to have a network namespace (let's say `weth_ns`) with a network interface connected to internet (`weth0`)
- I want to have a *different* network interface as a default route in the host namespace (`eth0`)
- I want to somehow be able to use things like `curl`, with *some* kind of interface, to transparently use the network *inside* that namespace to connect to internet.

So, like this.

[image: diagram]

I cannot seem to get it work. What I did so far:

```
ip netns add weth_ns
ip link set weth0 netns weth_ns
ip netns exec weth_ns ip link set dev weth0 up
ip netns exec weth_ns ip a # to see list to make sure it's there
ip netns exec weth_ns dhclient weth0

ip netns exec weth_ns curl website.com # works as expected
```

This sets up the namespace and puts the interface there. That makes curl work inside the namespace. Now I want to somehow use the isolated namespace connection from the host.

What I tried to do is set up a bridge, and set up iptables inside the namespace. So what I run:

```
ip link add veth0_left type veth peer veth0_right
ip link add bridge0 type bridge
ip link set bridge0 up
ip addr add 10.9.0.0/24 dev bridge0 # 10.9.0.0 is address I came up with
ip link set veth0_left master bridge0 up 
ip link set dev veth0_right netns weth_ns
ip netns exec weth_ns ip link set dev veth0_right up
ip netns exec mobile_ns ip addr add 10.9.0.1/24 dev veth0_right
```

This adds a brige; I can now successfully ping from namespace to namespace. So the bridge itself works.

```
ping 10.9.0.1 # works
ip netns exec mobile_ns ping 10.9.0.0 # works
```

And now I need to set up iptables to use the connection inside the namespace. I suspect this is where I do some kind of mistake. This is what I gathered from various online sources:

```
ip netns exec mobile_ns bash
# all following inside the namespace bash:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.9.0.0/255.255.255.0 -o weth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i weth0 -o veth0_right -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o weth0 -i veth0_right -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

(all the involved networks have  `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/<network>/forwarding` set to 1. From both inside and outside of the namespace.)

And... it does not work. My network should look like this now; but I cannot connect through curl. With either `veth0_left` or `bridge0` network interface.

[image: diagram 2]

I must be doing something wrong somewhere.

---

edit:

To specify what "does not work mean".

```
curl --interface bridge0 8.8.8.8
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 8.8.8.8 port 80: No route to host
```

```
curl --interface veth0_left 8.8.8.8
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 8.8.8.8 port 80: No route to host
```

---

When I try to see tcpdump, inside the namespace, I see `who-has` ARP requests, but only on the bridge interface. It seems to never "go" into the weth0 interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. The thing is, `curl --interface` does not magically get around routing.

As explained here

https://superuser.com/questions/1223177/why-does-curl-not-work-with-non-default-network-interface-in-centos-6